# How to display (format) epoch to full date with datacursor in a time series?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a custom formatter function to display both the Y and X coordinates of each point in my plot. As the plot is a time series, my x Axis is made of dates, which is making it difficult for me to display the exact same date as the plot is showing.

My code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from dateutil import parser
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import sqlite3
from mpldatacursor import datacursor
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.grid(True)
plt.ion()


def animate(i):
    datas = []
    dates = []

    con = sqlite3.connect('edgedb')
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT data, timestamp FROM edgedata')
    data = c.fetchall()

    for row in data:
        datas.append(pd.to_datetime(row[1], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').time())
        dates.append(float(row[0]))

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot_date(x = datas, y = dates, color = 'darkgreen', ls='-', marker='o')
    ax1.set_xticks(datas)
    plt.xticks(rotation=60, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
    #ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('$H:%M:%S'))
    ax1.grid(True)
    plt.ion()


def print_coords(**kwargs):
    return 'Valor medido : {y:.6f} às {x:s}'.format(y=kwargs['y'],
                                                    x=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(kwargs['x']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
datacursor(ax1, formatter = print_coords)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

This way, the cursor is displaying my Y value correctly, but my X comes as '1970-01-01 11:59:03' in the first point, increasing as it advances.

[image: Plot Cursor]

@edit:
As my friend Yuca called, I'm giving some points as they appear in my database.

```
(2.609698591082275, '2019-08-01 14:59:02')
(1.576077072171736, '2019-08-01 15:01:42')
(2.732782944225141, '2019-08-01 15:37:35')
(2.121527818052438, '2019-08-01 15:37:56')
(2.296660329191338, '2019-08-01 15:38:37')
(1.176709831423572, '2019-08-01 15:42:38')
(1.434814273623745, '2019-08-01 16:50:06')
(2.276750775178628, '2019-08-01 16:55:19')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the desired output/behavior?

Comment: I would like to get the right date in my cursor popup. As you see, for the point I'm clicking, the x axis is around 3 pm, but it's displaying 11:59:03.

Comment: can you include a sample of the data you're using?

Comment: The xticks are not spaced enough for this much incompatibility. Since I'm using other 3 scripts which includes hardware, I have no way of giving you a fully reproducible example, but I do believe that the plot part is enough for the question.

Comment: it's not about what you believe, it's about what's going to help  you get results faster, you need to only do `print(datas.head(5)` and same for `dates`

Comment: My point is that I believe it is some mistake with the conversion of a string do date, then the 're'conversion after using the epoch of the given date. All of these steps are given in my code. Thanks.

Comment: yes, and it's easier to check if that's the case if you provide sample data, but you do you

Comment: can you show the contents of `datas`?, the `.time()` part seems wrong

Comment: After I started using AutoDateLocator, I haven't touched the .time(). It worked good because it set my X axis with the right 'timeline' (right hours displayed). Now you told me, I just tested without '.time()', and it works and displays the right date for me (oh yea, thankssssss). The cost is that my  x Axis now displays the wrong date.

Comment: @Yuca just added 'ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))' with the removal of the .time(), and things are working fine. Thanks for your time and help, Yuka. Your comment solved it. Regards!

Comment: you're welcome little guy, happy coding